# Glory to Rome: play a role, perform no action

Tags: glory-to-rome

In Glory to Rome, if a player leads with a role, say Architect (using a Jack, as it is important to this example) can I follow with an actual Architect card if I either have no legal plays (all in-town sites are built or my stockpile is empty/not applicable to my under construction buildings) or if I want to perform no action other than to get an architect role into the pool at the end of the turn?

(Specifically this is so I can patron an Architect to win the game through the Forum's special ability, and Architects don't make it/remain in the pool.)

Answer (score 4):

In Glory to Rome, I find the general answer to "Can I do X?" questions is yes.  Your question follows that pattern, or else I'd be very surprised for this reason:

If you were forced to have a valid move at the time that you followed, then you could never really follow a legionnaire, because you might have your hand reduced to nothing but jacks, in which case you couldn't actually demand anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow with an actual **Architect** card, or choose to **Think** regardless of whether you have a legal action to play. I think I am understanding the [rules](http://www.cambridgegames.com/documents/GTR_Rulebook_Web.pdf) correctly. Your opponent can lead with a Jack, because a Jack can be used to lead or follow any role.

> **Jack** Fictional Roman citizens of all trades.  Jacks may be used to lead as or follow any role.

The Leader selects a role, and then each other player gets the option of Following, or Thinking.

> On each turn the player with the Leader Card (The Leader) decides what  type of turn (Role) it is going to be, and then each other player decides whether to participate (Follow) or draw cards (Think) Here’s how to play each turn:
>
> 1. If the Leader “leads” then in clockwise order around the table each other player may either:
>
>    - “think” and draw more cards (see below)
>    - “follow” by playing an Order card of the same role as the Leader
> 2. In clockwise order, each other player now gets to perform one action if they chose to follow, plus an additional action for each client he has of the chosen role.  Players who thought instead of following do still get to take actions for their clients!

The decision to "follow" is made by playing the Order card, and doesn't require a mandatory use of the action. This is supported in the rules by the Stairway Card.

> **Stairway** - Each time you execute an Architect action you may also chose to move an appropriate material into any opponent’s completed structure in order to immediately grant that structure’s function to all players ... You may perform the additional action **even if you choose not to use your Architect action**.